# Make an element float until a specified width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I use float in order to make a login form be displayd on the right side of the page in a black bar. But when if a user resize the window and make it have a small width the form goes up of the background-image. I want it to stop floating and do not move when it has width 100px. My website is http://greek.netii.net. 
I use the following **HTML code:**

```
<form action='index.php?action=login' method='post'>
  <ul id='loginbar'>
    <li>Email:<input id='logemail' type='text' name='email' />
        Password:<input id='logpass' type='password' name='pass' />
        <input class='button' type='submit' name='action' value='Login' />
    </li>
    <li><div id='forgotpass' onclick='forgotpass();'>Forgot Password?</div></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

And the following **css code:**

```
ul#loginbar {
    float:right;
    margin:25px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to float it to the right as it will come inwards on resizing......use this

```
ul#loginbar
{
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
right: 10px;
margin:25px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style-type:none;

}
```

and also in the parent container of the form or the body add

```
position: relative;
min-width: 600px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set minimum width and height using the following CSS properties:

```
min-width: 100px;
min-height: 150px;
```

to avoid components to be reduced too much.